# How to get a string containing the word connect from an array with strings?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
const arr = [
  '_ga=GA1.1.399070869.1649559884',
  'origin=s%3ACYm5bKjhAM1mfanrjJ8bqR_CAHffLVzj.MImlJ0gl2DTN%2BwRPmE0ZbQqI3nHwSVDt70DNyEd2Luw',
  'user=Zina',
  'connect.sid=s%3AvNWJDoh08zdqHE1k8P53CoDmLqI87GDO.%2BLdCgtZ%2F5gv%2BjdK1z0FiUoehYauJHCgrz9T2tZYX%2FI4'
]
```

I will not think in any way how to receive an index terms where the line begins with "connect".

get rid of suggestions like

```
arr[4]
```

since this line can be anywhere

Comment: did you try looping through the lines and test each one to see if it starts with "connect"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#findIndex` (or `Array#find`) in conjunction with `String#startsWith`.

```js
const arr = [
  '_ga=GA1.1.399070869.1649559884',
  'origin=s%3ACYm5bKjhAM1mfanrjJ8bqR_CAHffLVzj.MImlJ0gl2DTN%2BwRPmE0ZbQqI3nHwSVDt70DNyEd2Luw',
  'user=Zina',
  'connect.sid=s%3AvNWJDoh08zdqHE1k8P53CoDmLqI87GDO.%2BLdCgtZ%2F5gv%2BjdK1z0FiUoehYauJHCgrz9T2tZYX%2FI4'
];
let idx = arr.findIndex(x => x.startsWith("connect"));
console.log(idx, arr[idx]);
```

Comment: Thank you, the most important thing was in this matter, the remark in the comment that was deleted.... That I do not start with "Connect", but with a space...))) In any case, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a filter to find the value that matches the pattern you're looking for.

Here I use `array.filter` and `startsWith` method on strings.

```js
const arr = [
  '_ga=GA1.1.399070869.1649559884',
  'origin=s%3ACYm5bKjhAM1mfanrjJ8bqR_CAHffLVzj.MImlJ0gl2DTN%2BwRPmE0ZbQqI3nHwSVDt70DNyEd2Luw',
  'user=Zina',
  'connect.sid=s%3AvNWJDoh08zdqHE1k8P53CoDmLqI87GDO.%2BLdCgtZ%2F5gv%2BjdK1z0FiUoehYauJHCgrz9T2tZYX%2FI4'
]

const matches = arr.filter(value => value.startsWith("connect"))

console.log(matches)
```

Does this suit what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, the most important thing was in this matter, the remark in the comment that was deleted .... That I do not start with "connect", but with a space ...))) In any case, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use The [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods to get the line containing the word you want:

```js
const arr = [
  '_ga=GA1.1.399070869.1649559884',
  ' origin=s%3ACYm5bKjhAM1mfanrjJ8bqR_CAHffLVzj.MImlJ0gl2DTN%2BwRPmE0ZbQqI3nHwSVDt70DNyEd2Luw',
  ' user=Zina',
  ' connect.sid=s%3AvNWJDoh08zdqHE1k8P53CoDmLqI87GDO.%2BLdCgtZ%2F5gv%2BjdK1z0FiUoehYauJHCgrz9T2tZYX%2FI4'
]

const result = arr.filter(element => element.includes("connect"));

console.log(result)
console.log(result[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = ['_ga=GA1.1.399070869.1649559884',
    'origin=s%3ACYm5bKjhAM1mfanrjJ8bqR_CAHffLVzj.MImlJ0gl2DTN%2BwRPmE0ZbQqI3nHwSVDt70DNyEd2Luw',
' user=Zina',
' connect.sid=s%3AvNWJDoh08zdqHE1k8P53CoDmLqI87GDO.%2BLdCgtZ%2F5gv%2BjdK1z0FiUoehYauJHCgrz9T2tZYX%2FI4']
    
const result = arr.filter(element => {
    if(element.indexOf("connect") >= 0){
        return element
    }
});
console.log(result);
console.log(result[0]);
```